# MAVEN: This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures

Tags: maven

I am trying to add Oracle JDBC driver in Maven local repository using following command

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\Meharaj Fareedy\Downloads\ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar

But getting . [image: This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.]

Comment: Please add exception in text to understand

Answer (score 1):

Remove space from your "Meharaj Fareedy" directory  Or pass path in quotes
like -

without space

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\MeharajFareedy\Downloads\ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

With quotes

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="C:\Users\MeharajFareedy\Downloads\ojdbc6.jar" -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then it would work

Answer (score 0):

Use a quotes for the filename

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="C:\Users\Meharaj Fareedy\Downloads\ojdbc6.jar" -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Please fix the previous failures means project is depends on the other module or other something which has errors.

You may get the idea by running command one by one don't mix two or more together to execute.

You will get your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used wrong formatted options in Options field in maven task of pipeline or passed optional arguments through Command Prompt for executing maven task. Then you will get above error. You need to check the correct syntax for the options you are passing to maven as per maven version.

NOTE: Different maven version have slightly different syntax. Please look below highlighted fields in screenshots.

**ADO PIPELINE:**
[image]

**THROUGH CMD:**
[image]